# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}U_n$ where $U_n=\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^n\sin^2(t) dt$

Tags: integration

Writing $$\int\limits_0^n\sin^2(t)dt=\int\limits_0^{\pi E(\frac{n}{\pi})}\sin^2(t)dt + \int\limits_{\pi E(\frac{n}{\pi})}^n\sin^2(t)dt$$
Where E(x) designates the floor function of x

Use the squeeze theorem to find $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}U_n$

I tried to evaluate the Integral but it's specifically asked to use $\pi E(\frac{n}{\pi})$

Comment: Why not $$\cos 2t=1-2\sin^2t$$

Comment: You expressed the integral as the sum of two integrals.  Can you evaluate the left summand and find a bound for the right summand?

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n \sin^2(t)dt + \frac{1}{n}\int_0^n \cos^2(t)dt = 1$, so since I see no reason to prefer $\sin$ to $\cos$, I'd guess the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I am a visual thinker, so I will suggest what works for me. Imagine the shape and periodicity of the function you are integrating. Then understand why breaking it in parts is advantageous. That should be enough to make you able to squeeze the function between an upper and lower bound, and from that getting the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have:

$$\sin^2(t)=\frac12(1-\cos(2t))$$

It is clear that the function being integrated has a periodicity of $\pi$. Hence every integral through a whole $\pi$ period will have the same value. So, we have that:

$$\int\limits_0^\pi\sin^2(t)dt=\int\limits_0^\pi\frac12(1-\cos(2t))dt=\frac\pi2$$

Then, if we break down the integration as the function is suggesting:

$$\int\limits_0^n\sin^2(t)dt=\int\limits_0^{\pi \lfloor\frac{n}{\pi}\rfloor}\sin^2(t)dt + \int\limits_{\pi \lfloor\frac{n}{\pi}\rfloor}^n\sin^2(t)dt=\frac\pi2 \lfloor\frac{n}\pi\rfloor + \int\limits_{\pi \lfloor\frac{n}{\pi}\rfloor}^n\sin^2(t)dt$$

Notice that the integrand is always positive, so we can easily find an lower and upper bound by excluding the left term or letting it complete another cycle, which means that:

$$\frac\pi2 \lfloor\frac{n}\pi\rfloor<\frac\pi2 \lfloor\frac{n}\pi\rfloor + \int\limits_{\pi \lfloor\frac{n}{\pi}\rfloor}^n\sin^2(t)dt<\frac\pi2 \lfloor\frac{n}\pi\rfloor+\frac\pi2$$

$$\frac1n \frac\pi2 \lfloor\frac{n}\pi\rfloor<U_n<\frac1n\left(\frac\pi2 \lfloor\frac{n}\pi\rfloor+\frac\pi2 \right)$$

So, if we let $n \to \infty$, as both sides of the inequality tend to $1/2$, we have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n=\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the floor function. Since $$\cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2(t),$$ calculate the integral and use the squeeze theorem in the result.

Comment: I know but it's specifically asked in the question to use the floor function